# flutter: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<DropdownMenuItem<String>>'

Tags: android, ios, flutter, mobile, drop-down-menu

In my flutter app I have a dropdown and below is how I load data into it.

```
Consumer<ProductsImpl>(
                  builder: (context, data, child) {
                    print("consumer running");

                    return DropdownButton(
                        hint: Text(
                          "Please Select          ",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 14,
                          ),
                        ),
                        items: data.geProductAndTypeList.map((info) {
                          return DropdownMenuItem(
                            child: new Text(info,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 14,
                                )),
                            value: data,
                          );
                        }).toList(),
                        onChanged: (String newValue) {
                          setState(() {
                            _productdropDown = newValue;
                            print(newValue);
                          });
                        },
                        value: _productdropDown);
                  },
                ),
```

Below is the code where you can find `getProductAndTypeList`

```
class ProductsImpl with ChangeNotifier {
  NavLinks _navLinks = new NavLinks();

  List<FreshProducts> _freshProductList = [];

  List<String> _productAndTypeList = [];

  get geProductAndTypeList => _productAndTypeList;

  Future<void> geFreshProductsBySpecies(int id) async {
    try {
      var data = await http.get(_navLinks.getFreshProductsBySpecies(id));
      var jsonData = convert.json.decode(data.body).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
      _freshProductList = jsonData
          .map<FreshProducts>((json) => new FreshProducts.fromJson(json))
          .toList();

      print("Product sIZE: " + _freshProductList.length.toString());
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }

    //notifyListeners();
  }

  Future<void> buildProductAndTypeList(int speciesID) async{

    print("asasas");

    for(int i=0; i < _freshProductList.length ; i++)
    {
      if(_freshProductList[i].productSpecies.idproductSpecies == speciesID)
      {
        String str = _freshProductList[i].productCategory.name + ", "+ _freshProductList[i].productType.type;

        if(!_productAndTypeList.contains(str))
        {
          _productAndTypeList.add(str);
          print(str);
        }
      }
    }

    notifyListeners();

  }
}
```

When the dropdown is building, I am ending up with the following error.

```
[38;5;248m════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════[39;49m
[38;5;244mThe following assertion was thrown building Consumer<ProductsImpl>(dirty, dependencies: [_DefaultInheritedProviderScope<ProductsImpl>]):[39;49m
type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<DropdownMenuItem<String>>'


[38;5;248mEither the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
  https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=BUG.md
[39;49m

[38;5;244mThe relevant error-causing widget was[39;49m
    [38;5;248mConsumer<ProductsImpl>[39;49m
[38;5;244mWhen the exception was thrown, this was the stack[39;49m
[38;5;248m#0      ProductUIState._buildForm.<anonymous closure>[39;49m
[38;5;248m#1      Consumer.buildWithChild[39;49m
[38;5;248m#2      SingleChildStatelessWidget.build[39;49m
[38;5;244m#3      StatelessElement.build[39;49m
[38;5;248m#4      SingleChildStatelessElement.build[39;49m
[38;5;244m...[39;49m
[38;5;248m════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════[39;49m
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: value: data, //here you need to give some string but you are giving data

Comment: @HussnainHaidar so what's your solution?

Comment: give some index value in string instead of data. You can get index from map.

Comment: maybe try this value: data.indexOf(info).toString(),

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to create a custom get method for `_productAndTypeList` with the return type specified. When `get geProductAndTypeList => _productAndTypeList;` is used, it is returning a dynamic.

I made the below method.

```
List<String> geProductAndTypeList()
  {
    return _productAndTypeList;
  }
```